Error loading page with scrapy and scrapy playwright - Says to enable javascript
I am trying to access a webpage with scrapy and scrapy-playwright, however, I keep getting a 'Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker' messaged coupled with a timeout error. I have tried a variety of solutions but none seem to have worked...
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod


class WsjNewsJSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'wsj_newsJS_BACKUP'
        start_urls = ['https://www.wsj.com']

        
        custom_settings = {
            "DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS": {
                'http': 'scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler',
                'https': 'scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler',
            },
            "TWISTED_REACTOR": 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor',
            "PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE": "chromium",  # Optional: specify the browser type (chromium, firefox, webkit)
            "PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS": {"headless": False},  # Optional: configure Playwright options
        }

        def start_requests(self):
        # Enable Playwright for these requests
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    url,
                    meta={
                        'playwright': True,
                        "playwright_page_methods": [
                            PageMethod("wait_for_timeout", 5000),  # Wait for 5 seconds
                        ],
                    },
                    callback=self.parse
                )

        def parse(self, response):
            # Parse the response with rendered JS content
            html_content = response.text  
            sel = Selector(text=html_content) 

            print('Its working')

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Usually, this means that the target site uses antibot systems.
You may search for playwright-stealth and advanced scrapping techniques from r.

This is a comment, not an answer. s/scrapping/scraping

So, how do you want me to write the code to avoid antibots? Is it legal here?

Sure, why not? Telling people to search google isn't really an answer. At the very least, you could provide a site from those search results that you've personally vetted and verified working, although even that often results in your answer is in another castle.

That would be very much appreciated
